# how to consume a stream and make stream messages available to the caller

Tags: javascript, html

Given a streaming response of a backend api that produces a text output one line at a time, for example

[image]

Having read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#example-fetch-stream the client should look like this

```
function read(url) {
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#example-fetch-stream
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.body)
  .then(rb => {
    const reader = rb.getReader();
    return new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        function push() {
          reader.read().then( ({done, value}) => {
            if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
            }
            // todo: 
            // Get the data and send it to the browser via the controller
            controller.enqueue(value);
            // Check chunks by logging to the console
            console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
            push();
          })
        }
        push();
      }
    });
  })
  .then(stream => {
    return new Response(stream, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }).text();
  })
  .then(result => {
    // console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
}
```

The above works in a way that `console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));` outputs the stream messages one a time as they come (and depicted in the screenshot) and `return result;` outputs all of the messages once it finishes reading the whole stream.

Questions:

1. what `controller.enqueue(value);` actually does? I cannot understand what "// Get the data and send it to the browser via the controller" actually means. Can the caller utilise this somehow?
2. if the caller looks like below. how the `read` function should be written in order for `line` to hold a single stream message instead of the whole output?

**caller**:

```
let line = read('http://172.31.141.233:8000/stream/{{ output_data.token_id | safe }}')
console.log(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, I ended up manipulating the DOM outside of the HTML file, by doing this:

caller:

```
<div id="stream">
</div>
<script>
    read('http://172.31.141.233:8000/stream/{{ output_data.token_id | safe }}');
</script>
```

callee:

```
function read(url) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('stream');
  var pre = document.createElement('pre');
  pre.classList.add('h-16', 'overflow-y-auto');
  elem.appendChild(pre);
  pre.innerHTML += '> \n';
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#example-fetch-stream
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.body)
  .then(rb => {
    const reader = rb.getReader();
    return new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        function push() {
          reader.read().then( ({done, value}) => {
            if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
            }
            controller.enqueue(value);
            let line = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
            pre.innerHTML += line;
            // console.log(line);
            push();
          })
        }
        push();
      }
    });
  })
  .then(stream => {
    return new Response(stream, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }).text();
  })
  .then(result => {
    // console.log(result);
  });
}
```

which works, not sure how ugly it is though :( as I am not experienced with javascript.

Please feel free to post a better answer.